# How to get all files in a project that depend on a target file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dependencies, dependency-tree

Dependency tree takes a target file and returns an object tree of dependencies for the target file, e.g. files the target file is dependent on. I'm looking to take a target file and return an object/tree/structure of file(s) that depend on the target file, essentially the opposite of dependency tree. Does anything like this exist?